# Change user/executor of groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I am trying to execute a groovy script, and I need to assign the user to a specific value. The script gets called from Jenkins, and the executor is set to "SYSTEM", but I want to be able to change the User to an Admin account so it has permission to execute all aspects of the script.

The script is running on Windows which is why I need to change the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the user in this way: Go to `Run > services.msc > select Jenkins > (Right-click and select) Properties > Click on Log On tab > Select This account`

[image]

Comment: Maybe I wasn't 100% clear. I am running the Jenkins job as "Admin_Acct", and I execute a groovy script from the job. When I use "User.current();" in the script it says that the user is "SYSTEM" not Admin_Acct, and because of this it is giving me a permission denied error when I try to create a file. The property you mention is the correct user, I am trying to reassign the user in the script.

Comment: So you're saying that the Jenkins service is configured to run as "Admin_Acct" but still the Groovy script shows the user as "SYSTEM"?

Comment: Which flavor of Win OS are you using? There is this [Runas](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) command. You can give it a try.

Comment: Windows Server 2008. I need to be able to change the user from within the script so I can execute the script as a user who can create a file. The SYSTEM user cannot do this. I can't do a process outside of the script because it is automated in the Jenkins job.

Comment: You have to run the script that's present in Jenkins job using `Runas` command. It's not like doing something outside of Jenkins. You have to specify the command along with necessary parameters including the script name.

Comment: I am using the execute System Groovy Step. Can you tell me how I would use the Runas command along with this step, and get the script to use the right user?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62287/discussion-between-technext-and-rdemolish).

Comment: Seems like people are having [issues](http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-always-hangs-when-run-from-java_topic5013.html) when running `psexec` through Jenkins. Try it out. If it doesn't work then you can give a try to `Runas`.

Comment: psexec is a bit more complex than I wanted to go. Runas is not working either for me. :/

I could just create the file as an execute shell step, but that is adding another step to the job that I do not feel is needed.